# Matlab streamline plot not displaying all data provided

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a vectorial field on Matlab that was evaluated over a grid (built with meshgrid function) and I'm trying to plot its lines of force using the streamline function, but for some reason it's not plotting all the data I'm providing.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
[sx,sy,sz]=meshgrid(-2*raio/1.1:4*raio/1.1/(2-1):2*raio/1.1,-2*raio/1.1:4*raio/1.1/(2-1):2*raio/1.1, zeros(1,2));
figure;
plot3(sx(:), sy(:), sz(:), 'bo', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b');
grid;
xlabel('x (m)')
ylabel('y (m)')
zlabel('z (m)')
hold on;
streamline(x,y,z,Sx_z,Sy_z,Sz_z,sx,sy,sz);
axis tight
```

and here is the data of the field:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B25A3cTAmbDYc3E0S09Jb0ZJYUE/view?usp=sharing

For some reason, when I run the code, I get `img1`, which is not actually right, because `z` should go from `0` to approximately `1.2m`. However, if I divide `Sx_z` and `Sy_z` by a factor greater than `5`, I get something like `img2`, which is the kind of result I was expecting.
Does anybody know why I'm not being able to plot all the data without scaling `Sx_z` and `Sy_z`?

[image]

Comment: Try adding the optional tenth input to `streamline` `[1e-3 5e7]`, which defines the maximum step size and number of vertices for streamlines. It seems like Matlab is struggling with the integration and can't evolve the streamlines far enough with default parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, @David! Unfortunately, I was still not able to make the plot work properly. First, I tried the parameters you said, but the plot didn't appear (I waited a couple of hours...). Then, I tried many combinations of values for the maximum step size and the number of vertices. Many of them returned plots in less than a minute, but all of them were incomplete. In the ones with the most precision, the same happened as with [1e-3 5e7]...
Ah, by the way, I'm using Matlab R2015a.

Comment: It does seem like Matlab is struggling with the integration. Maybe you could use `ode45` to manually create the trajectories, it will give you more control.

Comment: The problem with using ode45 im my case is that the field I have is not from an ODE... It is derived from an electromagnetic field (which has an analytical expression). Maybe there is a way to plot streamlines from a symbolic function of x, y and z?

Comment: You can form a system of ODE's as `dx/dt=Sx_x(x,y,z)`, `dy/dt=Sx_y(x,y,z)`, and `dz/dt=Sx_z(x,y,z)` and solve those for the trajectories.

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea, David! I didn't have time to try it yet, but as soon as I do it I'll post the results.